# How to run the flash policy socket server?

Tags: python, django, sockets, ubuntu, sudo

I am try to build the simple chat app in django, But when I try to run the following python file,

```
./run_example.py
Listening on port 9000 and on port 843 (flash policy server)
FAILED to start flash policy server: [Errno 13] Permission denied: ('0.0.0.0', 843)
```

I am getting above error, because I need to use root permissions. But when I use `sudo`, my local `virtualenv` not working, it takes the root packages, but root didn't contains the packages. I need to run my django with `virtualenv`, I don't need to run root. How to solve this problem, Here my run_example.py code,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

PORT = 9000

import os

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

from socketio import SocketIOServer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Listening on port %s and on port 843 (flash policy server)' % PORT
    SocketIOServer(('', PORT), application, resource="socket.io").serve_forever()
```

Comment: Specify the path like <path-to-my-env>/bin/python manage.py runserver. That should solve help. So that it still allows you to use sudo along